# mkdir giving a 'File exists' warning, even though i call is_dir before attempting to create diriectory

Tags: php, linux

Well not much more to add, then what is in the title already, appart from maybe the actual bit of code:

```
    $dir = dirname($local);// $local is absolute path to the file

    if(!is_dir($dir));
        mkdir($dir, 0755, true); //if $dir is not valid dir, lets create one
```

So, any ideas how I am still getting the file exists warning?

And here is the actualu warning, if that is of any help:

```
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): File exists in       /var/www/Import/Photo.php on line 67
```

Comment: Why do you have a semi-colon (`;`) after your `if` statement? Does that not make the `if` statement useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_dir()` only tells you if a named path is a directory. There are other things that would block you from using `mkdir()`, such as a regular file, a symbolic link... you probably should replace your test with something like this instead.

```
if (!file_exists($dir))
```

Also, the terminating semicolon after your `if` statement means the `mkdir()` is actually not being guarded by this test in the first place; it will run every time.